# How to use Tapku library for iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I just found the Tapku library and would love to use the calendar, but am clueless as to where to start since I am new to iPhone dev. How do I go about presenting the calendar in one of my views?

Answer (score 9):

```
TKCalendarMonthView *calendar1=[[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init];
calendar1.delegate = self;
calendar1.dataSource = self;
[calendar1 selectDate:[NSDate date]];
[self.view addSubview:calendar1];
```

Add this in the .m file where you want to display.

Comment: Interesting how your rather simple and short answers all get around 10 up votes.

Comment: I have used [calendar1 selectDate:[NSDate date]]; code for getting today's date in calendar.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

have you looked in the demo project included in the library? i believe it has an example that would be very useful to you, and also, here is the developer documentation [gitHub docs](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki) that includes the calendar class structure.

Comment: yeah, I've looked at those... I guess I just don't know enough yet about iPhone programming for those to be useful. When I looked at the demo project everything was very different than what I'm used to doing out of my tutorials and books. I don't understand where to begin.

Comment: i'd begin by learning how the library works, either with the api documentation, or going into the code and figuring it out, its a useful thing for anyone to learn HOW a fairly complex library works, even if its just on the basic level. Tapku's naming is fairly well done, so it should be a logical process.  good luck.