# Does any library exist for showing the week view like the one in ipad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, calendar

I have checked the Tapku and Kal libraries for calendar. Both of them provide just month views. But i want a week view, that also for ipad. Is there any library or anything for showing week view like the one shown in the ipad calendar app?

Any kinda suggestions would really help. Thanks.

[image: Want something like this]

EDIT: 
I have found one [project](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui) which shows week view but its for iphone. I need it for the ipad. So i still need help!

Comment: From my knowledge, this does not exist in the open source world yet

Comment: modified the project which i have posted and got the solution. Go ahead and download the project i have given in my question.just resize the classes.nothing else. and enjoy. and have fun

Comment: You could check out this link. Answers here provide a good solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045709/how-to-use-tapku-library-for-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , it is available ............
just You need to search proper on google.....

for reference Have a look,
http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Comment: modified the project which i have posted and got the solution. Go ahead and download the project i have given in my question.just resize the classes.nothing else. and enjoy. and have fun.

Comment: @mayuur did you manage to show month view and list view as well as i native calendar?