# How to use/implement Tapku Day View calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

how to display the day view calendar for displaying events in may calendar?
I tried to search for demos or sample codes but I can't find any. I would also like
to know how to use its delegates. Thanks.

Comment: Refer [How to use Tapku library for iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9306494/932011)

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is for displaying month view calendar. What I want to know is how to use the day view calendar or day timeline. I have no idea how to used it I tried to search in the tapku documentation but there is no guide for day view.

Answer (score 1):

Use TKCalendarDayTimelineView  class

```
TKCalendarDayTimelineView  *dayView = [[TKCalendarDayTimelineView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
```